# Apex 5 Scatter + Bubble Chart

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I need to make a scatter plot where the markers change size based on a third value as per a bubble chart.  Is there any easy way to do this in Apex 5?  My searches for a plugin solution have turned up nothing.

Answer (score 1):

With Apex 5 yout don`t need a plugin solution anymore, just create a chart region and select bubble as Type within the Attributes tab.

Then create a simple SQL Query and select all values that you need for the plot.